# MySQL Stored Procedure - Calculate Pay with Varying Pay Rates

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I am facing an issue trying to come up with a MySQL stored procedure for a payroll report. Previously employee pay rates were only allowed to be changed at the start of a pay period. However now they can change during a pay period and the report needs to account for varying pay rates during a pay period. A pay period is two weeks.

I have the following query, which is really messy, it works but does not account for pay rate changing in the middle of a pay period.

*Note: The dates are hard coded as an example*

```
SELECT
    e.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID,
    CONCAT(e.LastName, ', ', e.FirstName) AS Resource,
    (SELECT rt.Description FROM Roles rt WHERE rt.RoleId = e.RoleId) as Role,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(td.BillableHours)
        FROM
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td,
            Projects p
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND p.ProjectID = td.ProjectID
        AND p.ProjectID NOT IN (24,29,606,614,746)
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
    ) AS RegularHours,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(td.BillableHours)
        FROM
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td,
            Projects p
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND p.ProjectID = td.ProjectID
        AND (p.ProjectID = 29 OR p.ProjectID = 614)
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
    ) AS PTO,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(td.BillableHours)
        FROM
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td,
            Projects p
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND p.ProjectID = td.ProjectID
        AND p.ProjectID = 24
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
    ) AS Holiday,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(td.BillableHours)
        FROM
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td,
            Projects p
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND p.ProjectID = td.ProjectID
        AND p.ProjectID = 746
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
    ) AS FloatingHoliday,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(td.BillableHours)
        FROM
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND td.ProjectID NOT IN (606)
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
    ) AS Total,
    (
        SELECT 
            epr.Rate 

        FROM 
            EmployeePayRate epr ,
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND epr.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
        AND epr.StartDate <= td.WorkDate
        ORDER BY epr.StartDate DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS PayRate,
    (
        (SELECT
            SUM(td.BillableHours)
        FROM
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND td.ProjectID NOT IN (606)
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
        )

        *

        (SELECT 
            epr.Rate 
        FROM 
            EmployeePayRate epr ,
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND epr.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
        AND epr.StartDate <= td.WorkDate
        ORDER BY epr.StartDate DESC
        LIMIT 1)
    ) AS GrossEarnings

FROM
    Employee e
WHERE (e.EmployeeID IN (SELECT t.EmployeeID 
    FROM TimesheetDetails tsd, Timesheets t 
    WHERE tsd.BillableHours > 0 
    AND tsd.WorkDate BETWEEN '2015-01-17' AND '2015-01-30'
    AND tsd.TimeCardID = t.TimeCardID
    ) OR e.Status = 'Active')
AND (e.ResourceTypeID = 2 OR e.ResourceTypeID = 4)
GROUP BY Resource
ORDER BY Role, Resource ASC
```

Ultimately the columns of the report should be.

EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, RegularHours, PTO, Holiday, FloatingHoliday,Total, and GrossEarnings.

I'm not very experienced with stored procedures but I'm thinking I would need to use a cursor to loop through each date and figure out which pay rate to apply to it.

Anyway this SQL will create the data structure.

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.17, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: timesheet_test
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.22-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `employee`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employee`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `EmployeeID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FirstName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CountryID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClientSitePhone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PersonalEmail` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClientEmail` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comments` longtext,
  `HRComments` longtext,
  `Status` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Expertise` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Years` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Payroll` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `PartTime` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `City` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `State` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateOfBirth` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `RoleId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ImmiId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ResourceTypeId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `UnderHoursAlerts` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `DateHired` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateLastWorked` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `RecruiterEmployeeID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrimaryPhone` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'H',
  `PreHire` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SSN` varchar(132) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Benefits` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'None',
  `HasPTO` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsReviewer` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ReviewerEmployeeID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `OffshoreGroupID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `CertificateOfInsuranceExpiration` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CertificateOfInsuranceNotes` longtext,
  `WorkersCompExpiration` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `WorkersCompNotes` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `employeepayrate`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employeepayrate`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `employeepayrate` (
  `EmployeePayRateID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EmployeeId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `StartDate` date NOT NULL,
  `Rate` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeePayRateID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unq_EmployeePayRate` (`EmployeeId`,`StartDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `projects`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `projects`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `ProjectID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ProjectName` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectDescription` longtext,
  `ClientID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ProjectBeginDate` date NOT NULL,
  `ProjectEndDate` date NOT NULL,
  `Active` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `Billable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `EngagementID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClassificationID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '9',
  `ProjectTypeID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ProjectID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `timesheetdetails`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `timesheetdetails`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `timesheetdetails` (
  `TimeCardDetailID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TimeCardID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ProjectID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `BillableHours` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
  `WorkDate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TimeCardDetailID`),
  KEY `fk_TimesheetDetails_Project_idx` (`ProjectID`),
  KEY `fk_TimesheetDetails_Timesheets_idx` (`TimeCardID`),
  KEY `idx_TimesheetDetails_WorkDate` (`WorkDate`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_TimesheetDetails_Project` FOREIGN KEY (`ProjectID`) REFERENCES `projects` (`ProjectID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_TimesheetDetails_Timesheets` FOREIGN KEY (`TimeCardID`) REFERENCES `timesheets` (`TimeCardID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `timesheets`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `timesheets`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `timesheets` (
  `TimeCardID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EmployeeID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `DateEntered` date NOT NULL,
  `PPEDate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TimeCardID`),
  KEY `fk_Timesheets_Employee_idx` (`EmployeeID`),
  KEY `idx_Timsheets_PPEDate` (`PPEDate`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Timesheets_Employee` FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeID`) REFERENCES `employee` (`EmployeeID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2015-02-23 15:49:19
```

This sample data should hopefully be enough.

```
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`employee` (`EmployeeID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Address`, `CountryID`, `Phone1`, `Email`, `Comments`, `Status`, `Payroll`, `PartTime`, `ResourceTypeId`, `Benefits`, `HasPTO`) VALUES ('1', 'Joe', 'Somebody', '123 Fake Street', '1', '555-555-5555', 'jsomebody@gmail.com', 'Not a real person', 'Active', '1', '0', '2', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`employee` (`EmployeeID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Address`, `CountryID`, `Phone1`, `Email`, `Comments`, `Status`, `Payroll`, `PartTime`, `ResourceTypeId`, `Benefits`, `HasPTO`) VALUES ('2', 'Roger', 'Rabbit', '123 Crazy Street', '1', '111-111-1111', 'rrabbit@gmail.com', 'Not a real person', 'Active', '1', '0', '2', '1', '1');

INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`employeepayrate` (`EmployeePayRateID`, `EmployeeId`, `StartDate`, `Rate`) VALUES ('1', '1', '2015-01-17', '20');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`employeepayrate` (`EmployeePayRateID`, `EmployeeId`, `StartDate`, `Rate`) VALUES ('2', '2', '2015-01-17', '25');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`employeepayrate` (`EmployeePayRateID`, `EmployeeId`, `StartDate`, `Rate`) VALUES ('3', '1', '2015-01-24', '50');

INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`projects` (`ProjectID`, `ProjectName`, `ProjectDescription`, `ClientID`, `ProjectBeginDate`, `ProjectEndDate`, `Active`, `Billable`, `EngagementID`, `ClassificationID`, `ProjectTypeID`) VALUES ('1', 'Project Mayhem', 'Create as much Mayhem as possible', '1', '2015-01-17', '2020-01-01', 'Y', '1', '1', '1', '1');

INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheets` (`TimeCardID`, `EmployeeID`, `DateEntered`, `PPEDate`) VALUES ('1', '1', '2015-01-17', '2015-01-30');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheets` (`TimeCardID`, `EmployeeID`, `DateEntered`, `PPEDate`) VALUES ('2', '2', '2015-01-17', '2015-01-30');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheets` (`TimeCardID`, `EmployeeID`, `DateEntered`, `PPEDate`) VALUES ('3', '1', '2015-01-24', '2015-01-30');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheets` (`TimeCardID`, `EmployeeID`, `DateEntered`, `PPEDate`) VALUES ('4', '2', '2015-01-24', '2015-01-30');

INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '8', '2015-01-19');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('2', '1', '1', '8', '2015-01-20');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('3', '1', '1', '8', '2015-01-21');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('4', '1', '1', '8', '2015-01-22');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('5', '1', '1', '8', '2015-01-23');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('6', '2', '1', '8', '2015-01-19');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('7', '2', '1', '8', '2015-01-20');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('8', '2', '1', '8', '2015-01-21');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('9', '2', '1', '8', '2015-01-22');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('10', '2', '1', '8', '2015-01-23');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('11', '3', '1', '8', '2015-01-26');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('12', '3', '1', '8', '2015-01-27');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('13', '3', '1', '8', '2015-01-28');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('14', '3', '1', '8', '2015-01-29');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('15', '3', '1', '8', '2015-01-30');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('16', '4', '1', '8', '2015-01-26');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('17', '4', '1', '8', '2015-01-27');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('18', '4', '1', '8', '2015-01-28');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('19', '4', '1', '8', '2015-01-29');
INSERT INTO `timesheet_test`.`timesheetdetails` (`TimeCardDetailID`, `TimeCardID`, `ProjectID`, `BillableHours`, `WorkDate`) VALUES ('20', '4', '1', '8', '2015-01-30');
```

I ran the following query against the test data above.

```
SELECT
    e.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID,
    CONCAT(e.LastName, ', ', e.FirstName) AS Resource,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(td.BillableHours)
        FROM
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td,
            Projects p
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND p.ProjectID = td.ProjectID
        AND p.ProjectID NOT IN (24,29,606,614,746)
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
    ) AS RegularHours,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(td.BillableHours)
        FROM
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td,
            Projects p
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND p.ProjectID = td.ProjectID
        AND (p.ProjectID = 29 OR p.ProjectID = 614)
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
    ) AS PTO,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(td.BillableHours)
        FROM
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td,
            Projects p
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND p.ProjectID = td.ProjectID
        AND p.ProjectID = 24
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
    ) AS Holiday,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(td.BillableHours)
        FROM
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td,
            Projects p
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND p.ProjectID = td.ProjectID
        AND p.ProjectID = 746
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
    ) AS FloatingHoliday,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(td.BillableHours)
        FROM
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND td.ProjectID NOT IN (606)
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
    ) AS Total,
    (
        SELECT 
            epr.Rate 

        FROM 
            EmployeePayRate epr ,
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND epr.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
        AND epr.StartDate <= td.WorkDate
        ORDER BY epr.StartDate DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS PayRate,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(td.BillableHours)
            *
            (
                SELECT epr.Rate 
                FROM EmployeePayRate epr 
                WHERE epr.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
                AND epr.StartDate <= td.WorkDate
                AND td.ProjectID NOT IN (606) 
                ORDER BY epr.StartDate DESC
                LIMIT 1
            )
        FROM
            Timesheets t,
            TimesheetDetails td
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
        AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE('2015-01-17')
        AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE('2015-01-30')
    ) AS GrossEarnings

FROM
    Employee e
WHERE (e.EmployeeID IN (SELECT t.EmployeeID 
    FROM TimesheetDetails tsd, Timesheets t 
    WHERE tsd.BillableHours > 0 
    AND tsd.WorkDate BETWEEN '2015-01-17' AND '2015-01-30'
    AND tsd.TimeCardID = t.TimeCardID
    ) OR e.Status = 'Active')
AND (e.ResourceTypeID = 2 OR e.ResourceTypeID = 4)
GROUP BY Resource
ORDER BY Resource ASC
```

The brings back the following record set.

```
EmployeeID, Resource, RegularHours, PTO, Holiday, FloatingHoliday, Total, PayRate, GrossEarnings
'2', 'Rabbit, Roger', '80.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, '80.00', '25', '2000'
'1', 'Somebody, Joe', '80.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, '80.00', '50', '4000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by condensing the sql you are using into something a little more readable:

```
Select e.employeeid as EmployeeID
  , Concat(e.LastName, ', ', e.FirstName) AS Resource
  , sum(case when p.projectid not in (24,29,606,614,746) then td.BillableHours else 0 end) as RegularHours
  , sum(case when p.projectid in (29,614) then td.BillableHours else 0 end) as PTO
  , sum(case when p.projectid = 24 then td.BillableHours else 0 end) as Holiday
  , sum(case when p.projectid = 746 then td.BillableHours else 0 end) as FloatingHoliday
  , sum(case when p.projectid != 606 then td.BillableHours else 0 end) as Total
  , EPR.Rate as PayRate
  , sum(case when p.projectid != 606 then td.BillableHours else 0 end) * EPR.Rate as GrossEarnings
From Employee e
  Join Timesheets t on e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
  join TimesheetDetails td on t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
  join Projects p on p.ProjectID = td.ProjectID
  join EmployeePayRate epr on epr.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
    and epr.StartDate <= td.WorkDate
where ((td.BillableHours > 0)
        or (e.Status = 'Active'))
  and td.WorkDate BETWEEN '2015-01-17' AND '2015-01-30'
Group by e.employeeid
  , Concat(e.LastName, ', ', e.FirstName)
  , EPR.Rate
```

If that looks acceptable, now we get into the meat of the matter the join to employee pay rate. We are going from a 1 to 1 to a many to 1, so that may change the grouping. The question is if an employee had two (or more) pay rates in a period, do you want to display a breakdown of what he made during each of the pay rates. I see your not doing a week at a time so you're not calculating overtime, so I'm guessing this is a pre-overtime overview report, meant for at a glance estimates of payroll, so knowing how many hours at which paygrade probably isn't important. bearing that thought in mind here is how we change the join:

```
  join EmployeePayRate epr on epr.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
    and epr.StartDate <= td.WorkDate
```

If you have a start date and end date for payrates the join changes to

```
  join EmployeePayRate epr on epr.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
    and epr.StartDate <= '2015-01-17'
    and ((epr.endDate is null) or (epr.endDate >= '2015-01-17'))
  join TimesheetDetails td on t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
    and ((epr.EndDate is null and td.WorkDate between epr.StartDate and '2015-01-30')
      or (epr.EndDate is not null and td.WorkDate between epr.StartDate and epr.EndDate))
```

You'll notice the or statements, we are trying to avoid using functions such as isnull() so we can use the indexes. which brings me to the next point, if you don't have an end date column, things get more complicated. But instead of writing up a whole solution that may not be necessary, let me know if that's the case and we will get it figured out.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no EndDate column in the EmployeePayRate table. It is assumed that once a new PayRate takes place the old one ends. As an example if my pay rate of $30 started on 1/1 and I have a new payrate or $40 start as of 2/1 all the hours before 2/1 would apply to $30, everything after would apply to $40 unless another new rate is entered at some point.

Comment: I ran your first query but it is bring back 120 hours for Joe Somebody instead of 80.

Comment: That is an interesting problem, I double checked and I'm using the project IDs the same as you, no doubling up or anything, and the joins are also the same so there shouldn't be any join expansion. I thought it might be multiple pay rates, but that's included in the group so if there were multiple pay rates you would get multiple rows for the employee.

Try this, add 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), td.WorkDate, 101) 
To the select list and the group by section, and see if Joe Somebody has any particular days that are doubled up.

Comment: It looks like it is counting Joe Somebody 10 days at $20 and 5 days at $50. However it should be 5 days at $20 and 5 days at $50

Comment: Ok that makes perfect sense, Joe was switched to $50 half way through the pay period so he has a week of join expansion at the 20$ rate. That makes life a little more difficult, But I'll edit the original to nest the pay rate to fake the start and end dates. should be up in a few.

Comment: Thanks you sir! Looking forward to seeing it!